# Executing nodejs code in my javascript html source

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I use express to send a html file to incoming **GET** requests:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

In that html file I declared(not sure which word to use here) another javascript file, script.js. via

`<script src="script.js"></script>` in the `<head>`

Is it possible to access nodejs functions like `require()` in this script.js?

If it is, what am I doing wrong/ what do I have to include to be able to use it?

Comment: in general, you can't use nodejs specific methods in a broswser - in the same way that you can't use browser specific methods/objects (`window`, `document`, etc) in nodejs

Comment: Node is interesting because it brings JavaScript to the backend which traditionally has been dominated by other languages and frameworks (Ruby, Python, PHP, etc) and I think this creates some confusion. Your backend (Node) is serving front-end javascript that has no relation to the server. The browser isn't aware of node, require, or any of those kinds of things. What are you specifically trying to do on the frontend?

Comment: that needs another get handling for "/script.js" if I truly understand because script tag with src opens new request when page loads(or is loading). Maybe you can render it on html page before sending response(using ejs) and have a <%- name %> tag in html file for targetting

Comment: You might want to check out browserify which does let you build node modules that can be served as clientside code

Comment: @JordanS I was trying to require a nodejs package called pg which I would have used to query data from my postgresql database and display it on the html page. From what I have heard of your responses it might be better to search for a way to query in jquery, which now that I think about doesn't seem too illogical...

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Oh it's working fine without so far...

Comment: @PhilippHemmelmayr You could consider using jQuery to make calls to a backend API that is connected to a database. You certainly don't want to be doing any database calls directly from jQuery or the front-end of your application. Use pg on the backend.

Comment: @JordanS yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing.
Code for anybody interested: http://pastebin.com/xAVzAuCD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `script.js` file runs in the browser and only has access to the features that a browser JS environment has.  Since there's no built-in `require()` in a browser, you can't directly use `require()` in `script.js` and the same is true for other node.js functionality that is not built into a browser environment.

If you need access to something that can only be done on the server (like accessing a server side database), then you can create a route on your server and use an Ajax call from `script.js` to send a request to that route and get a response.

For `require()` specifically, there are some third party libraries (not part of node.js or built into the browser) that allow you to get require-like functionality in a browser, but that's a special case.  Other node.js functionality like `fs.readFile()` is simply beyond the capabilities of a browser environment.